# Read Separate Directories & Create Separate RDDs in Parallel via Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, concurrent.futures, databricks

I need to read JSON files from separate source directories and create separate tables for each directory. I would like this done in parallel, but Spark doesn't support nested RDDs, so currently it's doing it sequentially. Is there a good solution to get those directories read/processed in parallel?

Here is a sample snippet of what I'm trying, but it doesn't work due to nested RDDs:

```
def readJsonCreateTable(tableInfo: (String, String)) {
  val df = spark
           .read
           .json(tableInfo._1)
  df.createOrReplaceTempView(tableInfo._2)
}

val dirList = List(("/mnt/jsondir1", "temptable1"),
                   ("/mnt/jsondir2", "temptable2"),
                   ("/mnt/jsondir3", "temptable3"))
val dirRDD = sc.parallelize(dirList)
dirRDD.foreach(readJsonCreateTable) // Nested RDD error
```

Changing the last line to dirRDD.collect.foreach works, but then the work isn't distributed and executes sequentially, thus very slow.

Also tried dirRDD.collect.par.foreach, but that only runs parallel threads on the driver and doesn't utilize all other nodes.

I looked into foreachAsync, but I'm not sure that asynchronous is necessarily parallel in this situation due to nesting.

This is using Spark 2.0 & Scala 2.11 via Databricks.

===========
Addition:

I tried foreachAsync which returns a FutureAction in Spark, but that gave an error as well.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
.
.
.
val dirFuture = dirRDD.foreachAsync(readJsonCreateTable)
Await.result(dirFuture, 1 second)
```

And apparently SimpleFutureAction is not serializable

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Scala [parallel collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) or [futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) to parallelize code running on the Spark driver. The Spark driver is thread-safe so this will work as expected.

Here's an example using parallel collections with explicitly-specified thread-pools:

```
val dirList = List(
  ("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/flights/departuredelays.csv", "departuredelays"),
  ("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/amazon/users/", "users")
).par

val pool = new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(2)

try {
  dirList.tasksupport = new scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport(pool)
  dirList.foreach { case (filename, tableName) =>
    println(s"Starting to create table for $tableName")
    val df = spark.read.json(filename)
    println(s"Done creating table for $tableName")
    df.createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)
  }
} finally {
  pool.shutdown() // to prevent thread leaks.
  // You could also re-use thread pools across collections.
}
```

When I ran this in Databricks, it produced streaming log output indicating that the two tables were being loaded in parallel:

```
Starting to create table for departuredelays
Starting to create table for users
Done creating table for departuredelays
Done creating table for users
```

This parallelism was also reflected on the Spark UI's jobs timeline view.

Of course, you could also use Java threads for this, too. In a nutshell, it's safe to call Spark driver APIs from multiple threads, so pick your JVM concurrency framework of choice and issue parallel calls to the Spark driver to create your tables.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426576/is-using-parallel-collections-encouraged-in-spark it isn't recommended:  
  
> "Any parallel execution inside a task is completely opaque for the resource manager and as result it cannot automatically allocate required resources"

Comment: That linked SO question is discussing parallelism _within_ a task, which is different than running multiple Spark jobs in parallel with parallel code on the driver.