# Passing Arguments into a thread in Scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark

I am learning Scala and as an exercise I am transforming some python (PySpark) code to Scala (spark/Scala) code. Everything was going ok until I started dealing with scala threads. So,  Do you now how can I re write the following code to scala?

Thank You in Advance!

```
def load_tables(table_name, spark):
    source_path = f"s3://data/tables/{table_name}"
    table = spark.read.format("csv").load(source_path)
    table.createOrReplaceTempView(table_name)

def read_initial_tables(spark):
    threads  = []
    tables = ["table1", "table2", "table3"]
    for table in tables:
        t = threading.Thread(target=load_tables, args=(table, spark))
        threads.append(t)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

Comment: Have you tried at all converting it yourself? Where are you stuck exactly? The Spark API is pretty much the same, regardless of the language.

Comment: Best way to ask questions here is to actually _try_ something, and then when it doesn't work the way you expected it to work, you can ask for help understanding why. What have you tried? What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

> ...passing arguments into threads...

Scala uses the Java standard libraries, and starting a thread in Java is a little bit different from starting a thread in Python. The main difference is, in Python you can choose any `target` (i.e., any function or callable object) for the thread's top-level, and you can pass in any `args` that you like. But when you start a Java thread, the top-level function must be a no-argument method named `run()` that belongs to an object that `implements java.lang.Runnable`.

Your Python thread's top-level function is `load_tables(table, spark)`. So, what you need in your Scala program is a thread whose top-level function is a `run()` function that *calls* `load_tables(table, spark)`.

I don't actually know Scala, but maybe the example on this web page will steer you in the right direction: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-java-thread-runnable-in-scala/

Basically, I *think* all you have to do is follow his example, and put your `load_tables(table, spark)` call in the place where his example says, "your custom behavior here."

Answer (score 2):

Solomon is right. I could not describe it better. Taking advantage of the syntactic sugar Scala provides over Java, your Python code is not longer in Scala:

```
  def load_tables(table_name: String, spark: SparkSession): Runnable = () => {
    val source_path = s"s3://data/tables/$table_name"
    val table = spark.read.format("csv").load(source_path)
    table.createOrReplaceTempView(table_name)
  }

  def read_initial_tables(spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
    val tables = List("table1", "table2", "table3")
    val threads = for {
      table <- tables
    } yield new Thread(load_tables(table, spark))
    for (thread <- threads)
      thread.start()
    for (thread <- threads)
      thread.join()
  }
```

You might ask where is the `run()` method, Solomon was talking about. Actually, the empty parentheses `()` after the `=` sign the `load_tables` starts with, represent the no-argument parameter list that is passed to the `run` method, while the body of the `run` method is the block of code between curly braces after the `=>` sign.
So a call to `load_tables` actually returns a new `Runnable` instance.

This is called a *Single Abstract Method* which is just a syntactic sugar that gives the impression that `load_tables` looks callable as in Python, but it's not actually. Only it's *return type* is, because it returns a `Runnable` object. This short version is only achievable because `Runnable` is a *Functional Interface*.

I'm not a specialist in Spark, so I'm not sure if this is the idiomatic way to code in Scala with Spark, but it's a good starting point to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not really what you are looking for but it could be interesting. Scala has some very convenient stuff for parallelization of collections with the method `.par`:

```scala
val parallelizedList = List(1, 2, 3, 4).par
parallelizedList.foreach(i => println(i)) // this is executed in parallel, not sequentially
// output:
// 2
// 4
// 1
// 3
```

So you can use this syntax with spark to read multiple tables in parallel:

```scala
def loadTable(tableName: String, spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
    val sourcePath = f"s3://data/tables/$tableName"
    val table = spark.read.format("csv").load(sourcePath)
    table.createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)
}

val tableNames = List("table1", "table2", "table3")
tableNames.par.foreach(name => loadTable(name, spark))
```

**EDIT**

- If you use Scala 2.12, parallel collections will be available. They have been moved to their own module in 2.13: [scala/scala-parallel-collection](https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections)

  - `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parallel-collections" % "1.0.0"`
  - `import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._`
- Be careful if the actions you execute on a parallel collection modify the same data. This can lead to non-deterministic behaviour (see @Alin Gabriel Arhip's comment below).
- Apparently, it is not really encouraged to use parallel collections with Spark (also see @Alin Gabriel Arhip's comment below), but I've never had any problem with them so far (although I usually only use them for very simple processing that I know won't use all available resources)

Comment: Note Scala's parallel collections used with side-effect computations lead to [non-deterministic behaviors](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html#side-effecting-operations). In particular, they are [not encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426576/is-using-parallel-collections-encouraged-in-spark) to be used with Spark. There have been multiple bugs with them, that's why they have been moved outside of the Scala standard library. You should have mentioned that you need an additional dependency to use them.

Comment: It can lead to non-deterministic behaviour when you read/rewrite on a `var` indeed. I usually use them when I want to deal with independent operations. As for their usage with Spark, I did not know that they were not encouraged. I've never had any problem so far, although I usually use them for very simple operations (for complex operations that are likely to take a lot of resources, I let Spark process the dataframes sequentially). For the dependency, as I use scala 2.12, I did not know that it has been removed from the standard library. I am going to add a note about that in my answer.